# Android Storage Access Framework (SAF) vs old file:// scheme

Tags: android

I have an audio recorder app which saves the recordings in both internal and external (removable) volumes. I have problems saving files on android 7+ in external (removable) volume. **More specific, this path appears to be read-only (read-only file system):**

```
Context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1]
```

**Should I switch from "file:/" scheme to Storage Access Framework (SAF) and it's documents URIs?** Is this the correct approach? I must mention the user can choose where to save the recordings, he can even create new folders for this scope.

Comment: `Storage Access Framework (SAF) ` is the only way to access removable memory from %version% version of Android (I unfortunately don't remember which verison exactly)

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thank you! In this case I have a problem since I use MediaMuxer class to encode and write the AMR-3GPP recordings and the it does not support content uri, only abs. path (setDataSource(String path)). Very pathetic from android team that it does not fully support the content uri.

Comment: "this path appears to be read-only" -- well, that may result in an array bounds exception, as `getExternalFilesDirs()` does not have to return a 2+ element array. However, if it returns a `File`, it should be read/write for your app. How have you determined that it is read-only?

Comment: and here *ugly workarounds* come in game - you may want first to write file to non-removable storage, and then copy it to removable one using SAF

Comment: @CommonsWare, removable real physical memory card storage (like microSD) is really read-only using regular approach. You can only use SAF to write to it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko: `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural) returns locations that are read/write for the app, where the second and subsequent locations are on removable storage. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)). *Arbitrary* locations on removable storage are at best read-only and ideally are deny-all, but this method returns locations that should be usable by the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Sorry I didn't mentioned, but I check for getExternalFilesDirs.length. I have a button called "External SD card" which is set GONE is the length is < 2. But in my case (samsung S7 android 7.0) when I want to create a file inside getExternalFilesDirs[1] I get EROFS: read-only file system exception. The same behavior I saw on some concurrent app. And this is against the documentation, where I am trusted that these app's private locations are read-write

Comment: @CommonsWare, the documentation is quite strange for that method. What about `There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files.`. It is completely wrong for removable storage, as no app should be able to write there, except the app, which owns this package.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I think that that documentation is invalid for removable memory

Comment: @VladMatvienko: You are welcome to believe what you want. Since that documentation was written *specifically* for removable storage, for a method that was added *specifically* for removable storage in Android 4.4 (when they finally locked down the rest of removable storage), I believe that the documentation is accurate. Plus, I just tested it, and it works fine (Samsung Galaxy Note 3, running Android 5.1).

Comment: @AlexandruCircus: Either your removable storage has problems (e.g., incompatible format), or Samsung screwed up that particular device, most likely. You may need to perform a test write to the removable device, and take steps if that test write fails for some reason. For example, you could set that button to be `GONE` if the test write fails.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Yes you are right, I should hide the button if the write test fails. I already performed a write test when the user approves the new recordings location and in the read-only case I show a popup informing this but I should do this in an earlier stage, when I decide weather or not to show that button. Here is my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audioRec&hl=en

Comment: @VladMatvienko - that copy workaround is out of discussion for me since when user tap on the stop button he should be able to play the recording instantly....This way I need to copy the whole file afterwards. And I hate to make workarounds only because android sdk is limited. I know SAF system is latter added, but this not excuse it is not fully covered by the other components like MediaMuxer or MediaRecorder.

Comment: @CommonsWare but that is not something that is my opinion. If the documentation is right, then `any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files`. This means that at least whole parent directory is writable by anyone with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: @AlexandruCircus, well, then you just have no way except disabling users from using removable storage. Actually that is how I did it in my app unfortunately.

Comment: @CommonsWare - after a phone restart, now I am able to write in the getExternalFilesDirs[1] :))

Comment: @VladMatvienko - yes, I could do this. But after a phone restart now I'm able to writhe in app's private folder in the removable storage (getExternalFilesDirs[1]). So my conclusion is I will continue with file:// scheme as long as I have access on removable card through methods like getExternalFilesDirs

Comment: @VladMatvienko: Ah, I see what you are complaining about -- my apologies. I took your "that documentation is invalid for removable memory" comment to mean the entire JavaDoc comment for `getExternalFilesDirs()`. My guess now is that you meant only that one bullet. AFAIK, the bullet referencing `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is correct only for the 0th element in the returned array, the one corresponding with "real" external storage. And so I agree with your complaint there.